# PostgreSQL equivalent to SQL Server's TVP

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

SQL Server has Table Value Parameters which allows you to pass an array of values as a parameter.

What is the appropiate way to achieve something similar to a PostgreSQL query so I can do something like:

`select * from product where id in ($1)`

I'm using Npgsql .NET library.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/3.0.5

Comment: Perhaps a more detailed explanation would help; where has `$1` come from in your example? Can you provide a full example in MS SQL?

Comment: Good point @IMSoP, I've added that info into the question. Using a .NET library.

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can use arrays instead of list of IDs: `... where id = any($1 ::int[])` where $1 is a string parameter looks like `{1, 2, 3}` Not sure about C# is it supports array parameters directly.

Comment: @Abelisto OH! I'm going to give that a go right now!

Comment: @Abelisto that worked PERFECTLY! Please add it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use arrays instead of list of IDs like:

```
... where id = any('{1, 2, 3}'::int[])
```

or

```
... where id = any(array[1, 2, 3])
```

which means that `id` is one of the array's items.

[Read more about arrays operators and functions.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

To pass array as a parameter from third party languages you can use at least first variant:

```
... where id = any($1 ::int[])
```

where $1 is a string parameter looks like `{1, 2, 3}`. Note that a space between `$1` and `::int[]` - it may be necessary for some clients.

Not sure about C# is it supports array parameters directly.

Comment: Note that Npgsql supports array types so you can definitely do the above from C#

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use IN operator in two ways:

```
expression IN (value [, ...])
expression IN (subquery)
```

Read in the documetation:
[first variant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20282), [second variant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) or [this overview](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/).

Comment: I'm trying to find out if its possible to pass as a parameter. With SQL Server using a TVP, you can do `where id in (select id from @ListOfIds)`, otherwise in PostgreSQL I have to generate the query each time with the list of Ids.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for inserts in C# using Dapper and Npgsql - it inserts 1, 2, 3 into a temporary table and selects them back out ordered descending, so it will print 3 2 1 to the console.  The trick here is the Postgres `unnest()` function, which expands an array to a set of rows:

```
var results = await conn.QueryAsync<int>(@"
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE DapperNpgsqlArrayParameterDemo (id int not null primary key);
    INSERT INTO DapperNpgsqlArrayParameterDemo (id) SELECT unnest(@numbers);
    SELECT id from DapperNpgsqlArrayParameterDemo order by id desc;",
    new { numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"found {item}.");
}
```